# AS3 novice struggles

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var animal:String ="Cat";


var isFish:Boolean;

isFish = isItAFish(animal);
trace(isFish);

function isItAFish (animal:String):Boolean {

    var fishArray:Array = new Array("haddock", "Trout", "Salmon", "Cod");

    for(var i:int = 0; i < fishArray.length; i++){

        if (fishArray[i] == animal){

            return true;

            break;
        }
    }
    return false; 
}
```

I just need help explaining this code guys and girls. The "isFish = isItAFish (animal); trace(isFish); is where I'm confused from.

Comment: it seems fine to me? "isItAFish" part is just calling the method named "isItAFish" right below, where it says "function...." and the trace part is just printing out to the the flash output window the value of "isFish"

Comment: Thank you for that. How would you explain the code from "for" until the end of the code?

Comment: Anyone?????????

Answer (score 2):

```
//animal is a string that contains the value "Cat"
var animal:String ="Cat";

//isFish is a boolean that will be used as a flag
var isFish:Boolean;

//isFish value will be changed from the outcome of the function isItAFish with the animal value.
isFish = isItAFish(animal);
trace(isFish);

//This function requires 1 string parameter and returns a boolean.
function isItAFish (animal:String):Boolean
{
     //fishArray is a list of all your possible fishes.
     var fishArray:Array = new Array("haddock", "Trout", "Salmon", "Cod");

    /*
    We iterate the array to see if animal ("Cat") is inside the fishArray possible values.
    This loop will run exactly the number of times of the array's content. In this case, 4 times.
    */
    for(var i:int = 0; i < fishArray.length; i++)
    {
        /*
        We are comparing the values of the fishArray against animal ("Cat").
        fishArray[i] holds the value of the current loop count.
        For example, the first loop will be fishArray[0] which is "haddock".
        The 4th loop will contain the value "Cod".
        */
        if (fishArray[i] == animal)
        {
            //If we find a match, we return 'true' and stop the loop.
            return true;
            break;
        }   
    }

    //IF the loop ends without any matches we return 'false'.
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: @hk111 if it helped be sure to mark the check mark or up vote the answer.